# Как иначе сказать "опуститься на Марс"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Земля — приземлиться, Луна — прилуниться, а Марс?

Comment: >я, собственно, в жизни ни одного из них не увижу. Как и они меня.  

Вы живете в XIX веке?
Вообще не о том разговор пошел. 
Вы можете междусобочики хоть на китайском разговаривать. Но предлагать это в качестве нормы для любого, стилистически не предопределённого, контекста - несколько самонадеянно.

Comment: Я предлагала? Не заметила. Говорила исключительно про себя.  
Но все же основывать норму _только_ на жаргоне профессионалов - это тоже не правильно. Должен быть компромисс.   

В конце концов, корабль же не "__в__ Марс" садится (__в__ лужу), а "на".   

А морской корабль - "ходит" (или на нем ходят?). В устах моряков. Но не запретите же Вы всем остальным говорить "плавает"?

Comment: >Говорила исключительно про себя.  
Я так понял, что вы поддерживаете "предыдущего оратора". Но хоть бы и "про себя". Что это меняет?

Comment: Господи, если бы не этот вопрос, я вообще никогда не говорила бы о посадке на Марс или другие планеты. Что так все заволновались-то?

Comment: Что тут предлагать, если "норма" (словарь, который я процитировала) говорит, что и самолет, и космонавты, и космические корабли могут сесть, @behemothus. А Вы или не заметили этого, или я даже не знаю.

Comment: Чего я, пардон, "не заметил"?  
Один словарь это не "словари", а бабки на лавочке - не образец для подражания.  
 
Я понимаю возмужение оингвистов, когда кто-то требует писать рОзыскноой или говорить квАртал и дЕбет потому дескать, что так говорят профессионалы, но простите тут вопрос не профессионального снобизма, а элементарного понимания.

ЗЫ Не могут сесть "корабли". Во всяком случае российские. Они сгорают в атмосфере. Посадку совершают **спускаемые аппараты**. Касательно шаттлов - тут вопрос классификации. Их все-таки относят к челнокам.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Теоретически - примарсится. Но в живой речи не используется. 
ЗЫ "Опуститься" - это ни в какие ворота не лезет. Совершить (мягкую) посадку.

Answer (score 0):

Еще варианты *сесть на Марс; прибыть на Марс*. В общем, нужно перефразировать. Собственно, а почему нельзя приземлиться на Марс? Земля же не только планета, но и грунт, почва, суша.

Comment: Можно, но не принято. Терминология сложилась во времена Королева,  Келдыша и Челомея. Для меня это авторитеты абсолютные.
Уж если Королев придумал "космическицй корабль", который на первых прорах был объекстом насмешек...   
Сесть можно только в лужу. Прибыть - для получения взыскания. Это для неумной фантастики.

Comment: Про лужу это Вы зря.    
Сесть:   
**7.** Прекратив движение, полёт, опуститься куда-л., на что-л. (о птицах, насекомых, летательных аппаратах, лётчиках и т.п.). Стрекоза села на ветку. Самолёт сядет на воду. Космонавты сели в пятидесяти километрах от запланированного места. Оса села на пирог.   
И еще 12 значений "сесть", согласно толковому словарю.

Comment: Может, для научного стиля другие варианты не прокатят, кроме как "совершить посадку". Но в контексте общей тематики почему бы и нет.

Comment: А что такое "общая тематика"? Если новостныая передача, то я против.   
Если "ненаучная фатастика", то я не комментирую.

Comment: То есть не говорят "(космический) корабль сел..." из-за ассоциации с лужей? Суеверно, однако :) Но нужны же еще синонимы, а то бедненько получается.

Comment: Нет, прото не говорят. Безо всяких ассоциаций.
А того, кто скажет, высмеют. Как чужака, севшего не в свои сани.

ЗЫ Вся авивция, а космонастика - трижды, на суевериях построена.

Comment: Хм, авиаторов понять можно :) Логика в этом есть, но опять-таки - "истина" такого рода доступна только для посвященных. А все остальные снова дураки, даже словарь.

Comment: А при чем тут словарь? 
Речь идет о том как сказать правильно, а не о том, как бабки на лавочке это прокомментируют. Да, прорывается иногда даже в новостные ленты, но это от безграмотности журналюг.

Comment: Конечно, __при.<чего-то>.ся__ на Марс - дело космонавтов, и они имеют право для этого использовать свой жаргон. Но лично я буду говорить "сесть на Марс", если уж вдруг заинтересуюсь темой. И то, что космонавты меня высмеют, меня абсолютно не колышет: я, собственно, в жизни ни одного из них не увижу. Как и они меня.

Answer (score 0):

Высадиться.
Так все официальные источники произносят при любой посадке на планеты.

Comment: Высадиться может экипаж (и то не всегда: можно совершить посадку, но не выходить из космического корабля), но не марсоход или другой летательный аппарат.

Comment: Да. Для межпланетных станций обычная форма - совершить мягкую посадку на поверхность планеты Х.  
Может и долго, но точно.

Comment: Причем тут журналисты, если словарь фиксирует возможность употребления?

Comment: Причем тут словарь, если там не указан контекст и стилистика?
Да и словарь толковый, а не технический.

Comment: Ну я же говорю: словарь - дурак :))

Comment: Заметьте, не я это сказал. (С)Велюров

Comment: Что тут поделаешь, у человека (@behemothus) просто __душа не лежит__ к такому словоупотреблению. А душа - важнее словаря! :-))